# Exotic functions, Pochhammer and red-black trees

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, asymptotic-complexity

Consider an initially empty RB-tree, which we insert m elements into.
Inserting an element takes O(log n) time, where n is the current number of elements inserted.
So I can write up the total time of m insertions, as: 
sum log(i) for i=1..m  == log(Pochhammer(1,m) ; courtesy WolframAlpha.

Indeed, the ratio of m*logm and log(Pochhammer(1,m) converges to 1, so I guess that is why I haven't seen log--Pochhammer anywhere before.

What other 'exotic' functions are in use in Computer Science? 
I know inverse-ackerman appears in Union-Find, etc...

Comment: You are aware that `sum log(i) for i=1..n  = Theta(nlogn)`? Proving it is simple: `sum log(i) for i=1..n  <= sum log(n) for i=1..n = O(nlogn)`. also: `sum log(i) for i=1..n >= sum log(i) for i=n/2..n >= sum log(n/2) for i=n/2..n = n/2 * log(n/2) = Omega(nlogn)`. Since we use asymptotic notation anyway - there is no point in using "Exotic function" which is asymptotically the same as a well knwon one.

Comment: @amit I see your point, but the question still stands :) Any other exotic functions (like inverse-ackermann) in use in CS?

Comment: Log star? The busy beaver function? I don't really understand the point of this question.

Comment: Of course log 1 + log 2 + ... + log m = log(m!), and therefore Pochhammer(1,m) is a different name for m! (factorial). I am disappointed people type questions to WA without thinking even for a moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) (which you may term "exotic") appear a lot in mathematics. The reason is that, by definition, their Taylor series have a simple form. Therefore, they appear as soon as you are using induction.

A lot of "standard" functions are in fact hypergeometric (also, most orthogonal polynomials are). The less used ones have fancy names, but they are of the same family.

*Also here, of course, sum(log k) = log(prod k) = log k!, so you don't even need fancy stuff. The fact that you get a Pochhammer symbol probably stems from the symbolic series summation method of Mathematica. Look eg. for Zeilberger's algorithm, which sums series using hypergeometric functions.*